# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту ошибку?

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-324:19 to override.

Comment: Сделайте миграцию на AndroidX. Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon А после миграции у меня не перестанут работать java файлы?

Comment: С чего бы им перестать работать. Тем более там предлагается бекап сделать, можно восстановить если работать не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас конфликтуют библиотеки com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 и androidx.core:core:1.0.0

Библиотеки androidx пришли на смену support. Они содержат одни и теже классы, потому нельзя в одном проекте использовать одновременно android x и support. Вскоре support перестанет обновляться, потому рекомендую все перевести на androidx. Это можно сделать автоматически, в меню Refactoring  в нижней части найдите кнопку Migrate to AndroidX. Сделайте бэкап, который вам предложит студия, т.к. иногда миграция проходит не без проблем и приходится еще что-то руками править